# overloading of builtin functions in NetworkX

Tags: python, ubuntu, overloading, networkx

I have installed NetworkX in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The folder is stored at  location usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/.

I have made some changes in Python file depth_first_search.py ( @ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/traversal /depth_first_search.py. )
The changes, given below , involves adding two lines and saving the files

```
visited=set(G.Sources)
print 'line after ',visited
```

The main program then calls for the above function as follows

```
Edge_List=list(nx.dfs_edges(SG,'16'))
print Edge_List
```

However the results obtained do not lead to printing 'line after'. Similarly the Edge_List is based on built-in function code and does not consider changes made by me. 
I believe that either I am not making the changes in appropriate files or the changes are not being executed. The changes are saved in the file.

Can someone help ? Thanks for the help

Comment: `import networkx` and `print networkx.__file__` will tell you where is a package used by interpreter.

Comment: Have you quit and imported networkx after the changes (simply using `import networkx` again won't do the trick, the cleanest thing to do is quit)